# Jenkins - Trigger Selenium test after deployment

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Jenkins, so please go easy!

I have a web application which we are developing, and we've started automating our release using Jenkins.

I also have a standalone Selenium WebDriver script which will perform a Smoke test on our web app. We usually run this manually each time there's a new deployment.

I heard Jenkins can automatically trigger Selenium tests. So what I did was to create a batch file, which will in turn call the Selenium script. I added a **Build Step** which will call this batch file.

What's happening now is Jenkins first Builds the WAR file, executes the batch (for selenium) and then deploys it to the target Tomcat.

But I was wondering if I could change the order to **Build WAR --> Deploy to Tomcat --> Call the Batch file that executes Selenium Test**. I want to do this as Jenkins Tests before deploying, which means my Selenium test still runs on the old build. This makes little sense, as I would rather run the Selenium test on the new build.

In short, is there a way I can execute the Batch file as part of a **Post Build Step** rather than a **Build Step**?

Comment: You can change the order of build steps simply by drag-n-drop. You could also create a separate selenium job which is automatically triggered by a (successful) build job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Würgspaß !!

I solved my problem by creating a separate Selenium Job which gets triggered automatically if my Build is successful. This way, I can create any number of downstream jobs to be triggered for a successful build.